# How to avoid naming unused variables from method return statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I will take an example first so that my question will be clear

Assume,

```
a,b = method1()
```

method1 in above statement will return both a,b values, but I will require only variable "b" throughout my program.

Is there any placeholder kind of thing in python so that it is not required to name the variable "a"

Something like,

```
_,b = method1()
```

is required. Thanks in advance

Comment: .. something a *lot* like that.  What happened when you tried it? ;^)

Comment: What @DSM said... and maybe `b = method1()[1]` so you don't even have a placeholder :)

Comment: @JonClements This is even better because of some weird side-effects when for example `a` refers to current frame which holds a reference to `a` (circular reference which causes troubles for garbage collector). This is a well known issue with `sys.exc_info()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python versions 2.x, since `_` is a valid variable name, what you wrote would work:

```
>>> _, b = method1()
```

You could use a name like `_ignore` to make your intention clearer. If you really need to not keep the variable around, just `del _ignore` on the next line.

From version 3.0 of Python, you can do this even with an arbitrary number of extra values:

```
>>> def method():
...    return 1, 2, 3

>>> *_, b = foo()
>>> b
3
```

See [What's new in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=tuple%20unpack#new-syntax) and [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for details.